# How to modify this function to exclude also the post belonging to a specific category?

Tags: php, posts, wp-query, functions, query-posts

I am very new in WordPress development and I have the folglowing problem.

I use this function (declared into the **functions.php** file of my theme) to modify the **main query** in such a way that the post having a specific tag are not displayed in my homepage:

```
function exclude_featured_tag_and_legacy_posts( $query ) {

    $tagId = get_tag_ID("featured");
    //echo("Featured Tag Id: + $tagId");

    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        //$query->set( 'tag__not_in', 'array(ID OF THE FEATURED TAG)' );

        $query->set( 'tag__not_in', array($tagId));
    }

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_featured_tag' );
```

As you can see this function is executed after the main query creation but before its executions and it modify the main query for the exclusion of the posts that have the tag named **featured**

Ok, it seems work fine. Now my problem is. How can I further modify my main query so that is also excluded the posts belonging to a specific category?

So I want that is excluded both the posts having the **featured** tag and the posts belonging to the **legacy** category.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

[`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) and [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) uses the exact same parameters, so if you need to know which parameters you can use with `pre_get_posts`, simply visit the `WP_Query` page in the codex.

There is another trick which you can use to get all the parameters (`query_vars`) you can use. Just add this on the page that you need to get the `query_vars` from, refresh the page, and this function will print out all the `query_vars` you can use with `pre_get_posts` and `WP_Query`

```
<?php global $wp_query; ?>
    <pre><?php var_dump($wp_query->query_vars); ?></pre>
<?php
```

To exclude a category, you can either use `cat` or `category__not_in`. Both take category ID's, `cat` take integers and `category__not_in` an array. So one of the following will do in your function

```
$query->set( 'category__not_in', array(ARRAY OF CAT ID's));
```

**OR**

```
$query->set( 'cat', 'ID's OF CAT');
```

You just have to make sure, your callback function in `add_action` and your actual function name does not match. `exclude_featured_tag` must be `exclude_featured_tag_and_legacy_posts`

Comment: Just checking in to see what is the status of your problem, is it resolved yet. If my answer solved your issue, please consider accepting my answer. If mine did not meet your standards and you manage to resolve this issue yourself, please consider posting and accepting your own answer. Would be nice to know how you've resolved this :-). If you are still having this problem, feel free to post a comment to my answer explaining where my answer are lacking. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check the [category parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) in the `WP_Query` documentation.